# How to regex with |?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
s6 = '''Male : abc
   Male : def'''
re.findall(r'(.*):|:(.*)', s6)
```

My output:

```
[('Male ', ''), ('            Male ', '')]
```

My expected output:

```
[('Male','abc'),('Male','def')]
```

When I do `re.findall(r'(.*):', s6)` I am getting `['Male ', '            Male ']` and with `re.findall(r':(.*)', s6)` I am getting `[' abc', ' def']`. When I use the `|` symbol I am getting the wrong output.

Disclaimer: Please don't do `re.split`

I have done `\w+` also which is working, but I want an expression in the below format. I have done `re.findall(r'\s*(\w+)\s*:|:\s*(\w+)', s6)`, which is not working individually. With `\s*(\w+)\s*:` and `:\s*(\w+)', s6` it is working.

*I want to know why with `|` it is not working.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternation operator `|` says "match this regex, or else match that regex". There is no way for the two subexpressions to match at once. If the first one is a match, the second will never even be examined.

To pull out stuff from both sides of a colon, simply craft a regular expression which captures text on both sides in the same match.

```
re.findall(r'([^\n:]+):([^\n:]+)', s6)
```

To trim whitespace around the matches, you need a more involved regex, except of course if you know that the matching strings will always be a single token (i.e. each is a single alphabetic string with no whitespace in it):

```
re.findall(r'(\w+)\s*:\s*(\w+)', s6)
```

Maybe for multiple tokens try

```
re.findall(r'\s*([^\n:]+?)\s*:\s*([^\n:]+?)(?=\s*(?:\n|$))', s6)
```

where we very conspicuously alternate between greedy and non-greedy matching to get the shortest possible strings which will still satisfy the regular expression.

Or you could turn around and turn the greed to your advantage:

```
re.findall(r'(\w+(?:[^\n\S]+\w+)*)\s*:\s*(\w+(?:[^\n\S]+\w+)*)', s6)
```

where we grab as many whitespace-separated tokens as we can into the capture, just as long as the whitespace does not contain a newline.

In some more detail, `e+` matches as many as possible *(greedy* matching), and `e+?` as few as possible *(non-greedy* or *stingy* matching). `(?=...)` is a lookahead which requires the following expression to match, without capturing or consuming the matching text. So `e(?=e)` when applied to the text *`eee`* will first match the initial `e`, and on the next iteration of `findall` find the immediately following one, even though it already participated in satisfying he previous match. And of course `(?:...)` is the plain non-capturing grouping parenthesis, and `[^\n\S]` is a character class which matches any one character which isn't a newline character and ... not *not* a member of the whitespace category - so effectively any whitespace except newline.

Notice also how we explicitly avoid matching a colon, or a newline, in the capturing expressions.

Novice: "How can I match all these strings?"
Master: "How can I match only these strings?"

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. It is rare to see a person wanting to learn here that some of us (*looking around the room*) are just posting copy-paste solutions and disregarding the fact that it doesn't answer what he asked.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't working because the first match consumes your anchor (the colon) so the second match never matches. You need assertions to fix that, but it's overcomplicated for this case:

```py
import re
compiled = re.compile(r'((\w+)\s*(?=:)|(?<=:)\s*(\w+))') 
s6 = '''Male : abc 
    Male : def''' 
re.findall(compiled, s6)                                                                                                                                                                            

# Output:
[('Male ', 'Male', ''),
 (' abc', '', 'abc'),
 ('Male ', 'Male', ''),
 (' def', '', 'def')]
```

So now you need to do post processing on the list you have, not recommended given this input. In short: don't use one anchor for two cases using alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

If you need all the words, just use `'\w+'`:

```
s6 = '''Male : abc
   Male : def'''
re.findall('\w+', s6)
```

Output:

```
['Male', 'abc', 'Male', 'def']
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try splitting your string on one or more non word characters:

```
s6 = """Male : abc
Male : def"""
words = re.split(r'\W+', s6)
print(words)

['Male', 'abc', 'Male', 'def']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just match what your need,

```
s6 = '''Male : abc
   Male : def'''
re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+', s6)
```